# How to fix Magento 2.0 Frontend Quick Add to Cart

Tags: magento2

Just installed Magento 2.0 for testing before moving to production.

One issue I am having is the "add to cart" at the category page where you hover your mouse on the product picture to "add to cart".
The page loads and directs you to the product page with a warning note that I needed to pick the attributes. Telling me that the initial picked attributes on the category page were not saved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is when you click "Add to cart" in category page, products are added to cart.

However, these products requires you to choose their options before you can add them to cart successfully. So, after adding them to cart, Magento check again and notify this error.

To solve this error, the best way you should do is using Magento 2 Quick view extension or Ajax cart support

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what makes this issue but I would recommend you use an Ajax cart such as [Mageplaza Ajax Cart](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-ajax-cart-extension/), I am using this extension, it works properly and I've ever not encounter any issue like that.